# Copy a value from one person in a group to everyone in a group

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data set in long format (multiple observations per ID), due to omitted information on prescriptions.  Each ID is part of a larger "set", and there are 50 or more sets all with one diseased ID.  One person per set has the disease, and the others don't.

```
dt <- data.table(ID = rep(1:10, each = 4),
             disease = c(rep(0, 16), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 12), rep(1,4), rep(0,4)),
             dob = c(rep(as.Date("13/05/1924", "%d/%m/%Y"), 4), rep(as.Date("15/09/1936", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), 
                     rep(as.Date("30/06/1957", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), rep(as.Date("19/02/1946", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), 
                     rep(as.Date("26/04/1939", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), rep(as.Date("13/05/1922", "%d/%m/%Y"), 4), rep(as.Date("18/10/1945", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), 
                     rep(as.Date("30/06/1957", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), rep(as.Date("19/02/1946", "%d/%m/%Y"),4), 
                     rep(as.Date("26/12/1939", "%d/%m/%Y"),4)),
             disease.date = c(rep(as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y"), 16), rep(as.Date("19/02/2006", "%d/%m/%Y"),4),
                              rep(as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y"), 12), rep(as.Date("13/11/2010", "%d/%m/%Y"),4),
                              rep(as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y"), 4)),
             set = c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20)))
dt <- dt[(disease==0), disease.date:=NA]
dt
    ID disease   dob      disease.date   set
 1:  1    0   1924-05-13      <NA>        1
 2:  1    0   1924-05-13      <NA>        1
 3:  1    0   1924-05-13      <NA>        1
 4:  1    0   1924-05-13      <NA>        1
 5:  2    0   1936-09-15      <NA>        1
 6:  2    0   1936-09-15      <NA>        1
 7:  2    0   1936-09-15      <NA>        1
 8:  2    0   1936-09-15      <NA>        1
 9:  3    0   1957-06-30      <NA>        1
10:  3    0   1957-06-30      <NA>        1
11:  3    0   1957-06-30      <NA>        1
12:  3    0   1957-06-30      <NA>        1
13:  4    0   1946-02-19      <NA>        1
14:  4    0   1946-02-19      <NA>        1
15:  4    0   1946-02-19      <NA>        1
16:  4    0   1946-02-19      <NA>        1
17:  5    1   1939-04-26   2006-02-19   1
18:  5    1   1939-04-26   2006-02-19   1
19:  5    1   1939-04-26   2006-02-19   1
20:  5    1   1939-04-26   2006-02-19   1
21:  6       0 1922-05-13         <NA>   2
22:  6       0 1922-05-13         <NA>   2
23:  6       0 1922-05-13         <NA>   2
24:  6       0 1922-05-13         <NA>   2
25:  7       0 1945-10-18         <NA>   2
26:  7       0 1945-10-18         <NA>   2
27:  7       0 1945-10-18         <NA>   2
28:  7       0 1945-10-18         <NA>   2
29:  8       0 1957-06-30         <NA>   2
30:  8       0 1957-06-30         <NA>   2
31:  8       0 1957-06-30         <NA>   2
32:  8       0 1957-06-30         <NA>   2
33:  9       1 1946-02-19   2010-11-13   2
34:  9       1 1946-02-19   2010-11-13   2
35:  9       1 1946-02-19   2010-11-13   2
36:  9       1 1946-02-19   2010-11-13   2
37: 10       0 1939-12-26         <NA>   2
38: 10       0 1939-12-26         <NA>   2
39: 10       0 1939-12-26         <NA>   2
40: 10       0 1939-12-26         <NA>   2
```

I'm interested in finding the age of everyone in that set on the date of disease for the case.
for example, how old is everyone in set 1 on 19/02/2006 (the cases disease date)? and in set 2 on 13/11/2010?

I've tried the data.table way:

```
cc[, age := dob - oa.cons.date, by = set]
```

which only worked for those with a `disease.date`

Any other thoughts I had involved copying the `disease.date` of each case to the controls in the same`set`, but I didn't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the first non-empty disease date within each `set` group to the whole column `disease.date`:

```
dt[, disease.date := disease.date[!is.na(disease.date)][1], by = set]
```

Then calculate `age`:

```
dt[, age := disease.date - dob]
```

Notice that time difference intervals are in days. You may divide them by 365 or treat them in any other suitable way. Maybe package `lubridate` can be useful here. With its help:

```
dt[, age := as.period(interval(dob, disease.date), unit = "years")]
```

or

```
dt[, age := decimal_date(disease.date) - decimal_date(dob)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(dt$dob - dt$disease.date[20])/365
```

Taking dt$disease.date[20] since there are some NAs in the disease.date column.

Since both columns are date objects, R automatically calculates the difference in two dates. The difference will be in terms of days, so dividing by 365 gives you the approximate age.

Comment: Apologies, I don't think my question was clear enough.  I've edited it now.  Your suggested code would only work if I had one set, but there are a lot more that have different disease.dates.

Comment: @Lb93 are you reading the different data sets in a list or in different data.frames ?

Comment: the data is in data.table/data.frame format and it includes all `sets`.  I've corrected the example to give more info

Comment: @Lb93 sorry I can't help much. I am still not sure of the structure of the dataset . Also, all the rows in the disease.date column for a dataset are supposed to have same disease.date? In the dataset you have shared there are two different disease.date values. Which value would you use to calculate the age?